# wvdial: The PPP daemon has died: Pty program error (exit code = 9)

Tags: 3g, wvdial, pppd

I tried to configure AnyDATA ADU890-WH modem to work in Linux, but I have not succeeded. I am client of Czech carrier O2 and using Ubuntu 14.04.

I have once managed to connect using Network Center, Mobile Broadband tab - but since then I have not succeeded.

This is my `wvdial.conf`:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = *99#
Stupid Mode = 1
ISDN = 0
Username = a
Init1 = ATZ
Password = a
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Dial Command = ATDT
Baud = 9600

[Dialer CDMA]
Auto DNS = 0
Init1 = ATQ
Init2 = ATZ
Stupid Mode = 1
Phone = #777
Idle Seconds = 0
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Username = 601xxxxxx@cz.o2.com
Dial Command = ATDT
Password = xxxxxx
Baud = 1500000


[Dialer three]
Init2 = ATZ
Init3 = ATQ0 V1 &D2 &C1 S0=0 +IFC=2,2
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
ISDN = 0
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
```

And this is important part of `/var/log/syslog` file:

```
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: Using interface ppp0
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB0
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx NetworkManager[740]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx NetworkManager[740]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx NetworkManager[740]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: MPPE required, but MS-CHAP[v2] nor EAP-TLS auth are performed.
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: Connection terminated.
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx NetworkManager[740]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jul 23 20:25:07 wigos-hp-lx pppd[5524]: Exit.
```

I have also found some guides how to set up the connection without `wvdial` - but these guides rely on starting the connection by `pon <connection-name>`, but when using this command, I get no output and nothing happens.

The modem supports also CDMA network, but the error when using `wvdial` is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By some trial and error, I found following section in my `/etc/ppp/options`:

```
# BSD licensed ppp-2.4.2 upstream with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# {{{
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
# Require the peer to authenticate itself using MS-CHAPv2 [Microsoft
# Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol, Version 2] authentication.
require-mschap-v2
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
# (note that MPPE requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
require-mppe-128
# }}}
```

Commenting out all those `refuse-*` and `require-*` options made the authentication (and connection) succeed.